# Compiler won't execute after upgrading from Unity 5.5 to the 5.6 beta

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, mono, beta

I've tried deleting the Library and Temp/Obj folders, twice now (rebuilding library each time) with no change.

I've removed my alternate compiler (Incremental Compiler.)

Reinstalled Unity 5.6.0b3 beta - no change.

There is no alternate UnityEditor.dll in my Assets folder.

**Creating a new project with Standard Assets only works fine and can be compiled.**

Here's a picture of the error: http://prntscr.com/e5kwng

> Could not start > compilationMissingMethodException: > Method not found: > 'UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.MonoScriptCompilerBase.GetProfileDirectory'. > UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.ScriptCompilerBase.BeginCompiling > () (at > C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/Compilers/ScriptCompilerBase.cs:40)

Comment: Hi, did you have any luck with that?

Comment: Yes, should've updated sorry - was caused by the third party Incremental Compiler. I tried removing it before, but you have to restart Unity for it to fix the problem, so I ruled it out.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but there's likely some leftover files from your compiler replacer left lying around.

Check the root of your unity project for anything about compilers, remove that, and your Assets/Editor folder.

In my case, I had to remove:

```
<Project Root>\Compiler\
<Project Root>\Assets\Editor\CompilerPlugin.dll
<Project Root>\Assets\Editor\CompilerPlugin.dll.meta
<Project Root>\Assets\Editor\CompilerSettings.cs
<Project Root>\Assets\Editor\CompilerSettings.cs.meta
```

Leaving this reply here incase it helps anyone else :)